# Cannot submit form when dynamically change the action value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using Bootstrap for my design and form validation.

I have encountered problems when changing the form action dynamically using JavaScript/jQuery. After submitting button, nothing happens and the submit button becomes disabled.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.btnSaveQuery').on('click', function(){
        $('#formId').attr('action', 'saveQuery').submit();
});
```

Here is my HTML form code:

```
<form id="formId" method="POST" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input name="description" class='form-control'
                placeholder="description" required autofocus />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success   btnSaveQuery">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: In your code I don't see anything with id `queryStringWrapper`

Comment: sorry, i already updated the id from 'queryStringWrapper' to 'formId'

Comment: This exact code works for me. I created a saveQuery.php file to test it and it receives the data correctly. SO the problem must be in order part of your code

Comment: Hello @Tivie are you using bootstrap and jquery too?

Comment: My Code is working when removing the 'required autofocus' key in input tags. but i need those for my validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to fix it. Either do not use `type="submit"` or do not submit it through code. Form is actually submitted on its click by default..

You can do this

```
<button class="btn btn-success btnSaveQuery" onclick="submitForm()">Save</button>

<script>
function submitForm()
{
$('#formId').attr('action', 'saveQuery').submit();
}
</script>
```

Or change the action before submit.. e.g on page load..

-------------**OR**---------------

I have not tested but following might work for you as you wish

```
$(".btnSaveQuery").on('click', function() {
   $('#formId').attr("action", "saveQuery");// do not submit. Its done by default
});
```

**Note:** make sure saveQuery(url) should exist

Comment: Hi Sami, i am so glad that you answered my question. removing the 'submit()' key works my app fine :) Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Please use return false in your code

```
$(".btnSaveQuery").on('click', function() {
   $('#formId').attr("action", "saveQuery")
});
```

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Kasera, I tried your suggestion but doesn't work for me. but it works fine when i removed the 'required autofocus' keys in my input tag but i need those keys for my validations.

Comment: you can use it without jQuery.submit()